# Creating Random Binary Generator

Tags: binary

Hi I am trying to write a code to output a random binary sequence.

This is what I have come up with but it keeps throwing an error when I try to compile it.

Can anyone help?

```
#include <StdAfx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{int x = rand();
if (x/2 == 0);
printf('1');
else 
printf('0');
}
```

Comment: For starters, there is no return statement in main. Second, your if statement ends in a semicolon when it should not

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `;` after `if (x/2 == 0)`

```
#include <StdAfx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  int x = rand();
  if (x/2 == 0)
    printf('1');
  else 
    printf('0');
}
```